# Lost Serial on Pi3 running Pixel

Tags: serial, uart, serial-console, pixel

I have just upgraded to the latest OS Raspbian Pixel and my serial connection has stopped working.  I know that the hardware is configured correctly as it worked pre-update.  I have updated to the latest firmware as well.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo rpi-update
```

I have verified that the pi3 is getting serial information.  I have employed the `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` in the /boot/config.txt.

The /boot/cmdline.txt it is as follows:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

I have then run

```
sudo systemctl disable hciuart
```

Running minicom

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyS0 -b19200
```

yields no results.  I have already read all the posts, like this one, [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3) and tried everything to no avail.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `/dev/ttyAMA0`?? If you *switched* the ports with the `.dt` overlay, `ttyS0` **would be the bluetooth module.**

Comment: @goldilocks sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA0 -b19200
 yields an error minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyAMA0: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, they've done something new and wacky then (read the section about `pi3-disable-bt` in `/boot/overlays/README.txt`).  There should be `/dev/serial0` and `serial1` symlinks, see which nodes they link to.

Comment: @goldilocks yes.  I have even tried sudo minicom -D /dev/serial0 -b19200
minicom: cannot open /dev/serial0: No such file or directory

Comment: Unfortunately you  have tried too many things. See "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911 What does `ls -l /dev/ser*` show

Comment: @Milliways after running that command it states lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov  8 08:28 /dev/serial0 -> ttyAMA0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Nov  8 08:28 /dev/serial1 -> ttyS0

Comment: After reinstalling NOOBS and NOT running rpi-update I get output on the ttyAMA0 in minicom.